# Script to log on with ssh and report back on success

Tags: powershell, ssh, scripting

I want to make a script that uses SSH to log into our various servers. The script should try to log into a list of machines with a default user to check if theres default passwords that need to be changed or other securtiy flaws that allow any user to log on. On success of logging in, it should send an email or similiar to let me know it found something.

Below is what I got so far. Is that a correct start? For some reason it fails to get the right client name from the textfile - I used a similiar looking script to get usernames and AD attributes and it worked there. I already got PoSH-SSH installed and it works when I manually invoke a connection.

Once that works I need a if/else that does something on a successfull login. How would I do that? What condition can I use to check if its successful or not?

thank you!

```
$clients = Get-Content C:\clients.txt

$List = ForEach ($client in $clients){
    New-SSHSession -$client -Credential test
   
}

$List | Export-Csv C:\clients.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: For the client name error this is probably due to the leading `-` char. Try `New-SSHSession -ComputerName $client -Credential test` or `New-SSHSession $client -Credential test`.
You can enclose the ` New-SSHSession` with a `try {} catch {}` block to detect connection errors instead of a `if () {} else {}` block

Comment: thank you, that worked out really well! Now the clients are recognized correctly from the txt. I think I am going to try and do a try / catch block for it now.